# Black screen with cursor after BIOS screen

Tags: windows-xp, boot

Here is a weird one,

Got computer with Windows XP.
It's getting stuck on a black screen with cursor blinking.

What did I do:
- Boot from installation CD (recovery option - command line):

```
  chkdsk C: /R
  copy D:\i386\ntdetect.com c:\
  copy D:\i386\ntldr c:\
  fixmbr
  fixboot
```

Chkdsk showed 0 bad sectors and no problems during scan.
dir on C:\ shows all directories and files in place (Windows, Program Files, Documents and Settings).
BIOS shows correct boot drive.

Still does not boot.
Not sure what to think of.

Please help.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "cursor blinking"? If it literally is appearing and disappearing repeatedly, that sounds very bad.

Comment: @TheElectricMuffin: Using drugs can cause a brain damage. =))

Comment: "*stuck on a black screen*" - What preceded this black screen?  Was it the VGA "Windows XP" w/black background or the "welcome" w/blue background?

Comment: Black screen was preceded by a SONY VAIO logo, which means right after BIOS screen.

Comment: Send an email to support@systemdiscs.com and I'll be happy to send you a free copy of our [XP boot repair CD](http://systemdiscs.com/). No guarantees, but hey, what do you have to lose.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: thanks for the CD, but it did NOT repair the problem... =( Will go to sleep now... =)

Comment: Interrupted installation? You did it or did it fail? Just want to rule out hardware probs

Comment: @kokbira: you are going wrong direction. I described you what you need to know, not more not less. If you noticed - I got this problem solved, so if you don't care about reading all answers, why should you care about solving it? Additionally: the problem is not related to such beginner's mistake as BIOS settings. From the way I positioned my question - you could easily tell the level of my knowledge on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it finally fixed, here are steps:

- Backup "Windows, Program Files, Documents and Settings" folders using True Image.
- Start new Windows installation with deleting all partitions and creating new ones.
- After first reboot during installation, boot from any Live CD and delete newly created folders by setup ("Windows, Program Files, Documents and Settings"), leave other files in place (don't delete them).
- Restore original folders from True Image.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a USB drive attached?  Disconnect any HD or USB storage devices if so.

Comment: Good guess, but USB devices are not connected and BIOS option for External Devices Boot is turned OFF.

Comment: I'm sure you've already checked this, but is the right hard drive set as the first bootable drive?

Comment: Yep, even tried to disconnect DVD-ROM...